# Project file is incomplete. expected imports are missing. vs 2017

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have updated visual studio and after update Asp Core API showing error [image]

[image]

Comment: Other reasons -see [.NetCore Projects are not loading after VS2017 update (target version 15.8.7)](//stackoverflow.com/q/52781191)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, deleted project (class library) and downloaded from tfs again, project was old and added "dotnet migrate" command from shell and working